# When does onActivityCreated get called in a Fragment's Lifecycle?

Tags: android, fragment-lifecycle

I am looking at the [Fragment's Lifecycle here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) but cannot see where [onActivityCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) gets called?

Comment: Here's a better diagram http://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ3QW.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)):

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this
>   fragment's view hierarchy instantiated

So basically `onActivityCreated` is called after the host activity `onCreate` has returned.

Comment: the link is broken